# Cannot align Google Custom Search Engine input form which has a lot of padding at the bottom by default

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-custom-search

I'm using the 'Classic' [Google Custom Engine Search](https://cse.google.com/cse/all) theme. It has a lot of padding towards the bottom and looks like this:
[image: It doesn't only look like this but it is actually it.]

The only way I can vertically align it to the middle is by using `padding-top` but doing this increases the height of the navigation bar by maintaining the bottom padding. I have tried setting `padding-bottom: 0`. Then I tried `vertical-align: middle`. It is, also, added as a menu list item so it should be in the middle of the nav bar just like the other menu items except that it is floated to the right.

I have tried the other Google Custom Search themes as well. The default one's search button is squished and the search icon in/on it does not show. The rest is plagued with padding problem with the only difference being the `padding-bottom` value - some have more and some less. This should probably rule out any styling problem with my site because I had the same style throughout the Google Custom Search Engine theme-changing.

I'm using `<script>...</script>`(JavaScript) version for embedding GCSE.

Sorry I couldn't create a fiddle because my site uses a large no. of PHP files.

Comment: Can you provide html and css output  of the page? Maybe by using view page source.

Comment: You want to see the website?

Comment: If it is publicly available yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looked at your page and yo dont use vertical align for other items. And margin is caused by a form inside the search div. So this should work:

```
.fp-search div {padding : 10px;}

.fp-search div div form {margin : 0;}
```

Comment: That didn't completely help. The bottom padding is still there and like I said, it's increasing the height of the nav bar by keeping the default bottom padding value constant.

Comment: Can you try now? If this wont work there should be incostancy between your and my browser, pc etc.

Comment: Works now. You're amazing. Thank you. :)